# Clearing form collection entirely

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, formcollection

I have an issue with Symfony 2.6 form collections. Removing elements from collection works, however only when at least one is present. If the last element is removed from DOM (leaving the collection container empty), no elements are removed from the collection after handling request.

Example:

I have a form with collection "children" and two children, "a" and "b". I remove the child "b" from DOM, save, removeChild is called, the child is removed. Now I also remove child "a", save, nothing happens - after refreshing the form the child is still present.
When dumping the main entity after the form has handled request, the child is present in it's collection as well.

Did anyone have similar problem and found a solution?

Comment: may be you show us some code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Daniel pointing me in a new direction I have found a solution. The method submit does in fact accept second argument - clear empty. Passing request to submit is however deprecated and will be removed in Symfony 3.0.
Handle request **does** in fact support the clear empty feature.
It is simply not passed manually, but based on the **request method**. If the method is post, clear empty is set to true. If method is patch, clear empty is false. In my case the method was patch, hence the issue.

Comment: I have a similar issue. Did you find a solution for PATCH method?

Comment: I found a solution

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got the exact same issue… The doc should warn about that, I will request them to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by 2 methods :

- as in symfony doc : [form collection doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)
- or with doctrine annotation : [doctrine orphanRemoval doc](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#orphan-removal)

But don't forget `cascade={"remove"}` annotation

Comment: Thanks for the anwser. The issue is however that you can't empty the collection **completely** - everything works as in docs, but if you remove **all** elements in the dom, the form get submitted without the collection and removeElement is never called. So neither oprhan removal or cascade remove will work, as the collection itself wasn't modified.

Comment: @Looted, I wonder if maybe your using "$form->submit($request, false)", which *won't* clear the field if its missing.   You'd need to make sure "$clearMissing" is set to true.

Comment: @Daniel, thanks for the hint. I use handleRequest however, since passing the request to submit is deprecated according to docs. It does not accept any arguments except for the request.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete all the items of a Collection of an Entity simply by:

```
$request['collectionName'] = null; //or empty array
$form->submit($request, false);
```

Problems arise when this $request comes from a javascript Ajax call:

```
var item = {field: 'test', collectionName: null};
ajaxPatchRequest(item);
```

since the null value is received as String "null". If collectionName is an empty array it will not be passed within the ajax call.
Thus, use the null value and apply a preprocessing before $form->submit():

```
$toPatch = array();

foreach($request->request->all() as $key => $value) {
    if($value === 'null') {
        $toPatch[$key] = null;
    } else {
        $toPatch[$key] = $value;
    }
 }

 $form->submit($toPatch, false);
```